# Maven install:install-file goal fails with Socket Error on Windows

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am using Maven for the first time . I am trying to add `spring-core.jar` to my local Maven repo.

**Maven command:**

```
C:\Users\user\.m2\repository>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=spring-core -Dversion=4.2.0.RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar
```

**Error message:**

```xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.5/plexus-utils-3.0.5.pom
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-digest/1.0/plexus-digest-1.0.pom
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
Dec 12, 2015 11:56:38 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.414 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-12T11:56:38+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven
    .plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect d
    ependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus
    -utils:jar:3.0.5: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.0.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unrecognized Windows Sockets error:
    10106: create -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Please some one help me to sort out this error and also let me know how to add external jars to my maven repository.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This message:

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
```

means Maven can't open the port 10106. Either this port is blocked or it's used.

Scan the ports, i.e. under Windows:

Windows+R ---> cmd ---> enter
netstat -b

Answer (score 2):

@letmedoit : Could you explain why you need to add manually an artifact to your local maven repository ?

IMHO, it would be better to create a pom.xml file and just run it.

Add this file (pom.xml) somewhere on your computer :

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>yourGroupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>yourArtifactId</artifactId>
      <version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>`

then just run the maven command into the directory where you put the previous file `mvn compile`.

It should do the dowload of the artifact, as you can see:

    `[INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building yourArtifactId 0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Downloading:     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.pom
    Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.pom (3 KB at 5.4 KB/sec)
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
    Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar (1028 KB at 78.9 KB/sec)
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ yourArtifactId ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/src/main/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ yourArtifactId ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 15.455 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-12T11:02:37+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/147M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`